# Problem with remote connection to MySQL database (Error 1045)

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access, windows-server-2019

I installed MySQL Server 8.0 on Windows Server 2019, during installation I created user `'superna' @ ' %'` with DBAdmin rights. When connecting from a local machine, there are no problems (`mysql -u superna -p`), but when trying to connect from a remote machine (`mysql -h 10.165.1.20 -u superna -p`), error 1045 is returned.
I checked the availability of port 3306 using nmap, port is open.

[image: select User, Host from mysql.user;]

[image: nmap -p 3306 10.165.1.20]

[image: mysql -h 10.165.1.20 -u superna -p]

[image: netstat]

When installing mysql server on Windows 10, such problems are not observed, the connection from the remote machine works correctly. Can you tell me what point in the settings I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The server was configured to NAT port 3306 to another machine on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if your **my.cnf** file have this line? If it hasn't, add it and restart mysql.

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: added this line to C:\ProgramData\my.ini, did not help. The my.conf file on Windows was not found.

Comment: This problem is only seen on Windows Server, on machines with linux and windows 10 is not observed. I tested on SLES 12 and Ubuntu 20.04.